# wait for sequelizer findOne to check database before returning a value

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. But i have this little function:

```
tripStatus (id) {



db.Trip.findOne({ attributes:['status'], where: {id: id} }).then(trip => {
    // trip will be null if not found else contains information about the trip

    if(trip!=null){

        console.log('found ', trip.dataValues['status']);
        return trip.dataValues['status'];


    }
    else{
        return -1;
    }
  }).catch(err=>{

      return -1;
  })


}
```

now I call it like this:

```
  var status=TripFunctions.tripStatus(1)
  //console out puts now in order of display on the console
  console.log(status) // gives undefined. FIrst out put
  'SELECT status from Trip WHERE id=1'
  "Found status 3"
```

It is returning value immediately it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the values inside of the Promise created by Sequelize but not returning that promise from your function. Resolve the values in the promise and return to so that you can wait for the results.

You should also use the `Instance.getDataValue()` function instead of accessing them directly, or better use use `raw: true` to not construct an object at all if you just need the `status` - it will return a plain JSON object. Probably using `Model.findById()` too.

```
tripStatus (id) {
  // return the promise
  return db.Trip.findById(id, {
    attributes:['status'],
    raw: true,
  })
  .then(trip => {
    // trip will be null if not found else contains information about the trip
    return Promise.resolve(trip ? trip.status : -1);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    return Promise.resolve(-1);
  });
}
```

Call it like so using a Promise

```
TripFunctions.tripStatus(1).then((status) => {
  // the status is available in the promise resolution
  if (status !== -1) {
    // do something
  }
});
```

It would be more concise to write this using `async/await`.

```
async function tripStatus (id) {
  const trip = await db.Trip.findById(id, {
    attributes:['status'], raw: true});
  return trip ? trip.status : -1;
}
```

Then you can call it with `async/await`.

```
const status = await TripFunctions.tripStatus(1);
if (status !== -1) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks doublesharp. I decided to try async/await and nodejs returning 'await is a reserved keyword' error, pointing to the callin line at const status

Comment: you might need to specify `function`

Comment: my edits are not going through but it works if I put await as above but for that to work, my calling function should also be async. So, async abc(req,res,next). Do you think that is good practice? I liked the conciseness of the async/await cases but not sure if I am doing a good style

Comment: Sure, an express route can be `async`.